# Form gives error if I don't fill all the details in Angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a reactive form to insert contact details.
Some of the fields are mandatory while others are optional.
The issue I have is if the user doesn't fill optional details fields and click on submit button I get following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate is null"
```

HTML Code:

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      contactType: ['', Validators.required],
      contactSubType: ['', Validators.required],
      referenceNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      contactStartDate: ['', Validators.required],
      contactLastVerifiedDate: ['']
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
   if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      const newContact = {
        contactType: this.contactForm.value.contactType,
        contactSubType: this.contactForm.value.contactSubType,
        referenceNumber: this.contactForm.value.referenceNumber,
        startDate: this.parseDate(this.contactForm.value.contactStartDate.toString()),
        lastVerifiedDate: this.parseDate(this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate.toString()),
    }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contact Type</label>
    <mat-select
      formControlName="contactType"
      class="form-control"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && contactFormf.contactType.errors }"
      required
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of contactTypes" [value]="obj.value"> {{ obj.viewValue }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactType.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactType.errors.required">Contact Type is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contact Sub Type</label>
    <mat-select
      formControlName="contactSubType"
      class="form-control"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && contactFormf.contactType.errors }"
      required
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of contactSubTypes" [value]="obj.value"> {{ obj.viewValue }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactSubType.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactSubType.errors.required">Name Type is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Reference Number</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      formControlName="referenceNumber"
      class="form-control"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && contactFormf.referenceNumber.errors }"
      required
    />
    <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.referenceNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.referenceNumber.errors.required">Reference Number is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="startDate"
      formControlName="contactStartDate"
      placeholder="Choose Start date"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && contactFormf.contactStartDate.errors }"
      required
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactStartDate.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="submitted && contactFormf.contactStartDate.errors.required">Contact Start Date is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="lastVerifiedDate" formControlName="contactLastVerifiedDate" placeholder="Choose Last Verified date" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="lastVerifiedDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #lastVerifiedDate></mat-datepicker>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <button>Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I make it Optional for user to submit form without entering Optional Details.Currently if user doesn't enter Optional details form gives error and if user enters details then it is successfully submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if there is a valid value before you parseDate... your function would be:

```
 onSubmit() {
   if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      const newContact = {
        contactType: this.contactForm.value.contactType,
        contactSubType: this.contactForm.value.contactSubType,
        referenceNumber: this.contactForm.value.referenceNumber,
        startDate: this.parseDate(this.contactForm.value.contactStartDate.toString()),
    lastVerifiedDate: (this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate != '' && this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate) ? this.parseDate(this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate.toString()) : '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have an error, but you can still prevent any error like that with something like

```
lastVerifiedDate: this
  .parseDate((this.contactForm.value.contactLastVerifiedDate || '').toString()),
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, then please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.